# Creating an Asterisk "application" to send GET requests from an endpoint via Phone Prompt

Tags: asterisk, pbx, sip-server, freepbx

*To start off, I'd like to state that this is my first dive into Asterisk related applications, and that I'm mostly a web developer.*

My workplace uses an MSP that installed Asterisk/FreePBX to manage our phone systems. The GUI is pretty intuitive and after reading and getting a bit lost I figured I'd come here and see how to go about setting this up.

I was tasked with building a simple application to reset user passwords through both a web interface (completed) and a phone interface - by dialing a number, dialing their ID card #, and then having their password reset. I'm a Systems Administrator and have access to all necessary applications, servers, etc. I can pick things up fairly easy and I was told I'd have enough time to figure this out and get it done.

This is what I need in terms of pseudocode when the user calls a specific extension:

```
recording('pwResetCardID'); // Play a "Please enter your ID # to reset PW" greeting. 

function getCardID() {
    cardID = input(); // Input 4-5 digits using the dialpad and save it to a var.
    verify = get('http://some.site/endpoint/cardid/'.$cardid); // Send a GET request.
    if verify { // If we got a successful response (200)
        recording('pwChanged'); // Tell the user their password has changed
    } else { // 
        recording('errorCardID'); // Otherwise tell them to try again
        getCardID(); // Recur the function.
    }
}

getCardID();
```

If the cardID is valid, their PW is changed on the other end of my node.js application, and I simply need the GET request to be sent out and the user notified of the success (or failure)

Answer (score 1):

You can start from doc describing asterisk dialplan

Probably need use func_CURL, Read application, Playbavk and Goto

You need put new dialplan in extensions_custom.conf and setup use it via custom apps module